# Why are force on charges depend on other charges?

Tags: electricity, coulombs-law

**Elaborately stating:** *In Coulomb's force , if there is a source charge Q and a test charge P . Why is the force of charge on P dependent on the charge value p.*

**What I think :**

1. F is proportional to distance between the charges due to Inverse Square Law .
2. F is also proportional to the charge of the source charge (Q)because of the electric field depends on the charge itself.
3. But I have no idea why it is dependent on the test charge? (P).

Comment: do you have the same question with gravitational fields? As an aside, physics doesn't always bring answers to fundamental "why"s. The role of physics is to observe the world and say "that's how it works". Asking why it works that way (e.g. why is there an electric force at all?) often leads you into the realm of metaphysics. In this case, the question is answerable as easy and intuitive symmetry arguments or comparisons to similar systems can be brought up to help you understand why it makes sense that it is this way. Do you expect an uncharged particle to be affected by the field?

Answer (score 1):

Newton's law says every action (force) has an equal and opposite reaction (force).

The only way to make the force of charge Q on P equal and opposite to the force of charge P on Q is to include both charges.

i.e. if $F_{Q->P} = \frac{kQ}{r^2}$ then either:

1. $F_{P->Q} = \frac{kP}{r^2}$ which violates Newton's law
2. $F_{Q->P} = \frac{kQ}{r^2}$ which both violates the symmetry of the problem and reintroduces your original objection of the force on a charge being dependent on that charge.

Incidentally, the $\vec{E}$-field at charge P will never depend on the charge of P. But the force will - just like the gravitational field g at mass m will never depend on the mass m, but the force of gravity will.

This makes sense because the force on any charge q in a field $\vec{E}$ is $\vec{F} = q\vec{E}$

Comment: I’m not sure if invoking Newton’s laws to explain an Electricity and Magnetism concept would be proper? Since the two theories are inconsistent (to my understanding).

Comment: @SillyGoose Newton's laws only break down when you entire the realm of relativity, i.e. when $\frac{v^2}{c^2}$ is not negligible.